# How to use two-character custom symbols on an R plot?

Tags: r, plot, symbols

I am making a scatter plot in R that uses a numeric labeling system for each point. There are 12 types of points, so I'd like to use the numbers 1 thru 12 as the point symbols. I'm trying"

```
pch=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","11","12")
```

But the issue is that it's rendering "10", "11", and "12", all as "1" on the plot and in the legend. Clearly, pch only accepts a one-character length symbol between the "". Is there a way to use a multi-digit symbol on a plot?

EDIT: Using `text()` helps with the plot, but the legend still cuts off at one character.

Here is the new full code:

```
fig <- ordiplot(mds1, type = "none", xlim=c(-200,200), ylim=c(-150,150), main = "Attractors in Human Subsistence Economy")
ordispider(mds1,  mclus1.out$clustering, label = FALSE, col="#00000050")
text(mds1$points, adj=0, labels=d2.1_label$subsis_ecol, cex=1, col=c("red","blue","green","orange","purple","magenta","cyan","brown")[mclus1.out$clustering])
legend(130,100, pt.cex=0.7, text.width=60, inset=10, y.intersp=0.8 , c("Gathering", "Hunting and/or \nMarine Animals", "Fishing", "Anadromous Fishing", "Mounted Hunting", "Pastoralism", "Shifting Cultivation, \nWooden Implements", "Shifting Cultivation, \nMetal Implements", "Horticultural Gardens \nor Tree Fruits", "Intensive Agriculture, \nNo Plow", "Intensive Agriculture, \nPlow"), pch=as.character(1:12), cex=0.7)
```

Here is the resulting plot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7325374/plot_zoom_png.png

Comment: use `text()` to plot the symbols. `?text`

Comment: Thank you. This solves half my issue. I've added to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my "answer" is to just edit the legend in a graphics program after exporting the plot. Not ideal, but it "works".

Answer (score 3):

yup as suggested:

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", ylim = c(1,12), xlim=c(1,12))
text(1:12, 1:12, pch=as.character(1:12))
```

what about?

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", ylim = c(1,12), xlim=c(1,12))
text(1:12, 1:12, as.character(1:12))
```

Comment: Thank you. using `text()` fixes the plot symbols, but using `pch=as.character(1:12)` doesn't work in the legend. I'll expand my question with the entire code and resulting plot.

Comment: Plot symbols works fine with each command you've given me, but it's the legend that is still giving trouble displaying two-digit symbols, even with `as.character(1:12)`